# Outputting XML via PHP and SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xml

Can anyone help me in by telling me how can I output my XML result via PHP? I have an sql database and written the function in PHP to parse the XML and I have debugged the page in Firefox (using the NET tab) which is bringing up a the correct response corresponding to my SQL statement however, I can't actually see the data, its just a blank page.

Here is the php file to write the XML:

```
<?php
  include("classes/database_connection.php");

    function parseToXML($htmlStr) 
       { 
        $xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr); 
        $xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr); 
        $xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr); 
        $xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr); 
        $xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr); 
        return $xmlStr; 
        } 

        // Opens a connection to a MySQL server
        $connection=mysql_connect ('www.numyspace.co.uk', '*********', '************');
         if (!$connection) {
           die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
           }


         $db_selected = mysql_select_db('********', $connection);
           if (!$db_selected) {
            die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
            }


        // Select all the rows in the ticket table
       $query = "SELECT * FROM ticket";
       $result = mysql_query($query);


       header("Content-type: text/xml");

       // Start XML file, echo parent node
       echo '<ticket>';

       while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
       // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
       echo '<tickets ';
       echo 'ticketID="' . parseToXML($row['ticketID']) . '" ';
       echo 'locationID="' . parseToXML($row['locationID']) . '" ';
       echo 'venue="' . parseToXML($row['venue']) . '" ';
       echo 'tPrice="' . parseToXML($row['tPrice']) . '" ';
       echo 'date="' . parseToXML($row['date']) . '" ';
       echo 'availability="' . parseToXML($row['availability']) . '" ';
       echo 'time="' . parseToXML($row['time']) . '" ';
       echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
       echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
       echo '/>';
     }

   // End XML file
   echo '</ticket>';

?>
```

Thank you and any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: The page's markup:

```
 <ticket><tickets ticketID="1" locationID="1" venue="The Cluny" tPrice="15" date="2012-04-17" availability="200" time="20:00:00" lat="54.978252" lng="-1.617780" /><tickets ticketID="2" locationID="1"..../></ticket>
```

Comment: Did you view the source? Is there any markup?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your resulting markup? Is there any output to the page prior to your header call?

Comment: Check my edit :) and no, nothing is echo'd before the 'output'..

Comment: Were those `....` at the end of your last `<tickets>` node intentional? Also, and this is important, is that SPACE at the beginning of your markup as a result of your code or when you just pasted it into the above?

Comment: The dots were intentional as the source is showing all the fields in the 'ticket' table and I didn't wan't to C+P it all. And the space is just when I pasted the code, thats unintentional, theres no space at the start of the output.

Comment: Have you also ensured there are is no other whitespace, such as newlines prior to your header call or PHP opening tag, or before/after  your PHP tags IN your included PHP file?

Comment: Yeah, I've taken all new lines and whitespace and still i'm getting the same outcome - the data is there it's just not displaying.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8489/discussion-between-josh-and-tim-johnstone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you have the XML declaration at the top of your XML.

```
echo "<?xml version='1.0' ?>";
```