# Mysql + PHP + Google Maps Api

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps-api-3

I have a database containing records of coordinates for squares.

using **google maps api** I would like to use the records on the database to draw the polygons.

I have some experience with PHP, and was thinking I could use PHP to pass database data to JavaScript.

I assume this can be done with XML, if so, would I write PHP to access the database and load the data into memory

**PHP**

```
require_once 'login.php';
$connection = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
if ($connection->connect_error) die ($connection->connect_error);

$query = "SELECT * FROM BC_BBA_SquaresCoordinates";
$result = $connection->query($query); 
if (!$result) die ($connection->error);

$rows = $result->num_rows;

for($j=0;$j<$rows;++$j){
    $result->data_seek($j);
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
$result->close(); 
$connection->close();
```

**JS**

```
downloadUrl("test1.php", function(data){
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var row = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("row");
    for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++){
      var squarenum = row[i].getAttribute("SQUARE_ID");
    }
});
```

I am not overly familiar with XML so possibly I am not coding the PHP correctly.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you'd be better I think passing your data from the PHP to the JS using JSON instead of XML.

Comment: Using JSON is a better idea, and maybe via an AJAX call? Depends on how/when you need to retrieve that data... See [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), it might help!

Answer (score 0):

I implemented part of this solution recently with XML. I did not draw any polygons (and would be interested to check out how you're doing that!), but I have been populating maps with lots of points stored in a MySQL db. I think I can help you work the XML. I wish I could point you to the sources I found and not just summarize them/share my solutions, but I couldn't turn them up quickly.

In the PHP, some clever person offered the parseToXML code [somewhere, maybe here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550739/outputting-xml-via-php-and-sql), it handles escaping characters. I used an iterative solution to generate the XML. Don't forget to specify that it's XML like the guy above `echo "<?xml version='1.0' ?>";` or `header("Content-type: text/xml");` before you start iterating AND close the opening tag (I used `<markers>`). I hope this helps.

**PHP:**

```
function parseToXML($htmlStr)
    {
        $xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr);
        $xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr);
        $xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr);
        $xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr);
        $xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr);
        return $xmlStr;
    }
$mapquery = "select PropertyID, Latitude, Longitude, from map";
$mapresult = mysqli_query($dbConn,$mapquery);
if (!$mapresult) {
    echo('Query Error');
    quit();
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

echo '<markers>';

if ($mapresult->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $mapresult->fetch_assoc()){
            echo '<marker ';
            echo 'propId="' . parseToXML($row['PropertyID']) . '" ';
            echo 'lat="' . $row['Latitude'] . '" ';
            echo 'lng="' . $row['Longitude'] . '" ';
            echo '/>';
        }
    }
echo '</markers>';
```

**JS**

```
  downloadUrl("map.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var propId = markers[i].getAttribute("propId");
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point
          });
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for that,

I was able to draw ~11000 polygons on a google map using

var SquareCoords = [
            {lat: parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("latone")), lng: parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lngone"))},
            {lat: parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lattwo")), lng: parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lngtwo"))},
            {lat: parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("latone")), lng: parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lngone"))},
            {lat: parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lattwo")), lng: parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lngtwo"))},
            {lat: parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("latthree")), lng: parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lngthree"))},
            {lat: parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("latthree")), lng: parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lngthree"))},
            {lat: parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("latfour")), lng: parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lngfour"))},
            {lat: parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("latfour")), lng: parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lngfour"))},

```
        ];

        // Construct the polygon.
        var drawSquare = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: squareCoords,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 3,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.35
        });
```